# Android - layout: positioning buttons issue

Tags: android, android-layout

In my App-Layout I have a Relative Layout which contains 7 Buttons in a row. Now I want to add another Button (@+id/IB_Summe) at the beginning of the row. But in GraphicalLayout and on my device the first two Buttons (@+id/IB_Summe and @+id/ImageButton01) are overlayed. They are not besides? What am I doing wrong?

my xml-Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/Buttonleiste"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="120px"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
 android:paddingTop="2dp"
 android:paddingBottom="2dp" android:background="@drawable/gradient">

<Button
     android:id="@+id/IB_Summe"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/graph"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:background="@layout/selector_empty_square_on"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
     android:lines="1"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:text="@string/summe_symbol"
     android:textColor="@color/my_white"
     android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IB_Summe"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:background="@layout/selector_empty_square_on"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
     android:lines="1"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:text="@string/euro_symbol"
     android:textColor="@color/my_white"
     android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/menuDiagram"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ImageButton01"
     android:background="@layout/selector_empty"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:lines="1"
     android:maxHeight="38dp"
     android:text="@string/Hour"
     android:textColor="@color/my_white"
     android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/menuExtrasButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuDiagram"
     android:background="@layout/selector_empty"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     android:lines="1"
     android:maxHeight="38dp"
     android:text="@string/Day"
     android:textColor="@color/my_white"
     android:textSize="30sp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuExtrasButton"
    android:background="@layout/selector_empty"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxHeight="38dp"
    android:text="@string/Week"
    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuCounter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuInfo"
    android:background="@layout/selector_empty"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxHeight="38dp"
    android:text="@string/Month"
    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuSetting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuCounter"
    android:background="@layout/selector_empty"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxHeight="38dp"
    android:text="@string/Year"
    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuTarif"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuSetting"
    android:background="@layout/selector_empty_square"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxHeight="38dp"
    android:text="@string/kws_symbol"
    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second button use `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IB_Summe"` instead of `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IB_Summe"`. Notice the plus sign. That should work

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working with the plus sign in the android:layout_toRightOf tag.

Comment: Oops, the second Button contains android:layout_alignParentLeft="true".
As I removed this tag, it works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, those little things when you copy-paste views. Pulled my hair a few times because of these. Use styles, they simplify views and make it harder to make such typos:)